# WSAStartup link error

Tags: linker, evc, wsastartup

I am using EVC++ and I want to compile the program which uses the sockets.
I've included

`#include <winsock2.h>`

And I have included in project properties a path to Ws2.lib
But still get the error at link step:

> error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol WSAStartup referenced in function ...

How to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 17):

`#pragma comment(lib,"WS2_32")`
after all `#include`'s

Comment: This worked for me on Visual Studio. Basically we need to provide the symbols for the functions to the linker while linking.

Answer (score 9):

You haven't linked your program with the winsock library. The Winsock 2 library is called ws2_32.lib (static) or ws2_32.dll (dynamic). It should already be on your system; you just need to tell your compiler/linker to link your program against it. The method of doing this varies by compiler, and unfortunately I'm not familiar with EVC++.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms911778.aspx
It is written there about how the WSAStartup works.
It uses ws2.dll.
But nothing is written about ws2_32.dll

Answer (score 1):

Have seen this error in codeblock IDE using MinGW.
Tried many ways but finally found this solution.

Add(your the path for MinGW installed in your system)
  C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\libws2_32
  C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\libwsock32
in codeblock IDE.

How to add:
   Go to project.
   build options.
   Linker setting.
   click add of link library.

And its done.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, that problem was solved by adding
`#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")`